# clickable text in richtextbox

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I want to make a clickable text through code in c# (its not a URL just ordinary text) so when i click that text it do linkclicked event.
It is for a dictionary so when I search something and in the description there is a word same from the storage I can click it to search that word.

```
for (int j = 0; j <= jml[i]; j++)
        {
            richTextBox4.AppendText(j + 1 + ". ");
            string[] desk = sk[i, j].Split(' ');
            for (int l = 0; l < desk.Count(); l++)
            {
                for (int m = 0; m < kata.Count(); m++)
                {
                    if (desk[l] == kata[m])
                    {
                        richTextBox4.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
                        desk[l] = LinkArea;
                    }
                }
                richTextBox4.AppendText(desk[l] + " ");
                richTextBox4.SelectionColor = Color.Black; 
            }
            richTextBox4.AppendText("\n");

        }
```

my code for the moment(for the hyperlink type text just the color that work)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how to make a clickable text without www. in front of it

Comment: Have you resolved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way but if you know what you want it is not hard to build.

- Step one is to decide just how the clickable text is **defined**, read: What are the **separators**?

  - If you want single words it is rather easy. One way is using a regEx to identify words in a RTB. If you don't like the built-in way to define a word, I can post a code with user-defined separators.. But maybe you are happy with what have already.
  - If you need whole phrases (including spaces) to be clickable as one whole entity then you will have to be a little more inventive:
  - either you can add special characters around the phrases
  - or you can replace the spaces by non-breakable spaces
  - Or you could write a complete map into your text, but that probably defies your purpose.
  - Anything but simple words will mean that you will need to apply some changes to your text.

The result should be a function that can find the start and the end of the clickable text and return the clicked word/phrase.

- Step Two is to look up the text in a `Dictionary<string, string>` and do what you want to do with the value, e.g. show the translation in a Label:

---

```
if (dictEnGE.ContainsKey(theClickedWord)) 
    label.Text = dictEnGE[theClickedWord];
```

- For this to work you must first prepare the dictionary by adding the key-value pairs: The keys are the clickable texts and the values are whatever you need to find:

---

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictEnGE = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dictEnGE.Add("house", "Haus");
dictEnGE.Add("man", "Mann");
dictEnGE.Add("mouse", "Maus");
//..
```

So the whole solution is: Prepare a dictionary, code the Mouseclick event to find the clicked text, look up the text in the dictioanry, do your thing with the value you find..

Update:  Here is a function to get the clicked word:

```
string getWordAtIndex(RichTextBox RTB, int index)
{
    string wordSeparators = " .,;-!?\r\n\"";
    int cp0 = index;
    int cp2 = RTB.Find(wordSeparators.ToCharArray(), index);
    for (int c = index; c > 0; c--)
    { if (wordSeparators.Contains(RTB.Text[c])) { cp0 = c + 1; break; } }
    int l = cp2 - cp0;
    if (l > 0) return RTB.Text.Substring(cp0, l); else return "";
}
```

and here is how you could use it:

```
private void richTextBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    string word = getWordAtIndex(richTextBox1, richTextBox1.SelectionStart);
    if (dictEnGE.ContainsKey(word)) aLabel.Text = dictEnGE[word];
}
```